# Table not touching the browser border

Tags: html, css

my problem is that i have a table and it continues even if it touches the edges of the browser and i don't know how to solve this
Here IS m'y code from the table

Important to mention I use PHP

```
function create_Chat_Table($text){
    $pseudo=$_GET['DATA_Pseudonyme'];
    $output="<form method='get'>";
    $output .= "<table>";
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($text); $i++) {
        $explode = explode(",", $text[$i]);
        if (isset($_GET['DATA_Pseudonyme'])){
            $href='index.php?page=chatrooms&room=' . $explode[0] . '&DATA_Pseudonyme=' . $pseudo;
    }else{
           $href='https://foxi.ltam.lu/2TPIF2/tarlu584/Projet_WSERS_Zelda/index.php?page=Pseudonyme';
        }
        $output .= "<td id='table_chats'><a href=$href>$explode[0]<img src='" . $explode[1] . "' alt='Chat Room Image' width='100px'></td>";
     }
    $output .= "</table>";
    $output.="</form>";


    return $output;

}
```

```
table{
    display: inline-table;
    margin: 1em;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
table td{
    border: solid 3px;
}
```

Its for m'y school project WE are doing a chatroom[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehWWr.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You should try a max-width: 100% in css, it should prevent the table to grow more than available space.

If content is to huge to fit in your windows, you might also check for overflow property.

Also, as i see on picture, table might not be the better choice for rendering. You should try flexbox css, maybe with a flexbox-wrap to wrap content to next line when it's too big.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want your table to be responsive. This means it will automatically resize to fit in the browser window.

One way to do this would be to add style="overflow-x:auto;"

source: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_table_responsive.asp

But since you're using forms, I assume you're using bootstrap which comes with some built in classes like class="table-responsive"

Bootstrap also has a grid system which you can read about here:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that's not exactly what I want.  I just want if for example I have more than 5 TDs on the same line that the 6th goes to the line below

Answer (score 0):

**Solution!**

1. Just Change Some Lines Codes here is example:

```css
table{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr; /* To display how many columns you want to see like here there are 5 1fr it means equal 5 fractions respect to screen width it means 100% responsive */
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr; /* To display how many rows you want to see like here there are 2 1fr it means equal 2 fractions/rows respect to screen width it means 100% responsive */
    gap: 10px; /* gap or spacing between rows and columns */
    margin: 1em;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
table td{
    border: solid 3px;
}
```

**Feel Free To Ask Doubts!**